# Using variables in multiple functions, throughout an Object

Tags: javascript

**Base**

- I would like to use some variables that are set from another function within an object
- One function, `onUpdate:` waits for a call to be made from somewhere else in the application
- Second function, `onRelease:` triggers after a mouse click

**What I am trying to achieve**

There are some `DOM` elements I need to use for both functions. However, a `document.onload` won't work here, so I am thinking that I'll need to store them in some sort of `JavaScript object`.

**Restrictions**

(Elements are only used in this `Object` and must be declared inside the `Object`)

---

**note**: This is a custom built `app` so it may seem a bit confusing, but I only need to know if this can be done in the current situation

---

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to use `Javascript Objects` or some sort of function that stores/gets the `DOM` elements so they are usable throughout an `Object`?

**Code**

```
var ObjB = exports.ObjB = ObjA.extend({

    /* Something to contain the DOM Elements E.g.
     UI = {
         domElement: document.querySelector('#dom')
     }, 
    */ 

    onUpdate: function() {
        if(domElement.hasClass('class')) { 
            // logic using other elements
        }
    },

    onRelease: function() {
        if(domElement.hasClass('class')) { 
            // logic using other elements  
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: is the element `#dom` guaranteed to be available at the time the functions are called?

Comment: I think you mean *JavaScript objects*. JSON is something completely different.

Comment: @t.niese yes, the DOM elements will be available when the functions are ready to be called

Comment: should the `UI` be the same for all *instances* created from `ObjB` (`obj1 = new ObjB(); obj2 = new ObjB();`   `obj1` and `obj2` share the same `UI` ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to use the dom element more then once, and you would like to avoid to call the selector everytime you want to use the element you could do it this way, but be award that this will only work if you dont remove or add the required elements later (after you called `this.setupUi()` the first time), because `UI` will only be *initialized* once:

```
var ObjB = exports.ObjB = ObjA.extend({

    onUpdate: function() {
        this.setupUi();

        if(this.UI.domElement.hasClass('class')) { 
            // logic using other elements
        }
    },

    onRelease: function() {

        this.setupUi();

        if(this.UI.domElement.hasClass('class')) { 
            // logic using other elements  
        }
    },

    setupUi : function() {
        if( !this.UI ) {
           this.UI = {};
           this.UI.domElement =  document.querySelector('#dom');
           //add all other elements that are required by the object
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Nice one. I did try something similar to creating a function, but I was missing the keyword `this` and the checking of an existing object. thank You